# Como abrir a opção de seleção de certificado dos navegadores?

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-chrome, certificado-digital

Estou trabalhando em um projeto utilizando PHP/HTML/JavaScript onde será feita a assinatura com certificado digital dos clientes, onde os mesmos irão receber um documento PDF e poderão assinar utilizando um botão. Quando esse botão for clicado preciso que seja aberto a opção de seleção dos certificados digitais instalados na máquina do cliente conforme imagem abaixo e que o certificado escolhido fique disponivel para a manipulação no PHP. Como faço para abrir esse console de seleção de certificado no chorme/firefox quando o cliente clicar no botão de assinar?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa configuração fica no servidor, e cada um tem seu jeito de configurar (mas *geralmente* se chama "client authentication" e tem uma opção "certificate" ou algo assim) - com isso, será pedido o certificado do cliente quando este acessar o site. Além disso, alguns browsers não mostram essa janela se só tiver um certificado instalado no cliente (apenas se tiver 2 ou mais, para que vc escolha - se tiver só um, usa o que tiver) - mas acho que alguns mostram a janela sempre, só não lembro se dá para configurar esse comportamento, cada browser deve fazer do seu jeito.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para assinar documentos você necessitaria da chave privada do cliente. Esta janela só oferece a chave pública. Portanto, não é possível realizar esta ação da forma que está planejando.

A critério de curiosidade, muitos órgãos do poder judiciário ainda utilizam applets do Java para terem acesso ao certificado instalado na máquina do cliente e, assim, realizar assinaturas em documentos. Nível baixo de segurança em benefício da praticidade.

Comment: Veja esta pergunta no stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057537/digitally-sign-document-with-php

Comment: Sem o certificado do cliente, seja o arquivo A1 ou acesso ao token A3, é impossível assinar um documento.

Comment: Existe algum problema de segurança permitir que o cliente faça o upload do certificado A1 contendo a chave privada para o meu servidor de modo que a assinatura seja realizada?

Comment: Quando trabalhei com isso o cliente final enviava o certificado num processo interno da empresa e um funcionário cadastrava. Não utilizávamos a aplicação para tal. Depende bastante da sua política de privacidade visto que se trata de um item que exige bastante proteção.

Comment: Muito Obriagado!